# Finding pairs in a table in R

Tags: r

I need to identfy pairs of numbers in a table in R. The structure of the table is as follows:

```
   user_A   user_B   counter
1       1        2         5
2       1        3         3
3       2        1        10
4       2        4         8
```

I want to check if for each pair, an opposite one exists, e.g. pair (1,2) and pair (2,1), and if so - sum the counter value for both pairs.
As a result, I want to have an output in a form of a table like this one:

```
   user_A   user_B   sum   bi_directional
1       1        2    15             TRUE
2       1        3     3            FALSE
3       2        4     8            FALSE
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anything you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

We can `sort` the first two column row wise with `apply` (MARGIN=1), `cbind` with the third column ('d1'), get an index of duplicates of the first two column ('i1').  Convert to 'data.table' (`setDT(d2)`), grouped by 'user_A', and 'user_B', get the `sum` of 'Counter' and the first row of 'i1'.

```
 d1 <- setNames(cbind(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), df[3]), names(df))
  i1 <- duplicated(d1[1:2])|duplicated(d1[1:2], fromLast=TRUE)

 d2 <- cbind(d1, i1)
 library(data.table)
 setDT(d2)[, list(counter=sum(counter), bi_directional=i1[1L]) ,.(user_A, user_B)]
 #  user_A user_B counter bi_directional
 #1:      1      2      15           TRUE
 #2:      1      3       3          FALSE
 #3:      2      4       8          FALSE
```

---

Or another option is

```
setDT(df)[user_A > user_B, c('user_B', 'user_A') := 
       list(user_A, user_B)]
df[, list(counter= sum(counter), bi_directional= .N>1), 
                                   by = .(user_A, user_B)]
#     user_A user_B counter bi_directional
#1:      1      2      15           TRUE
#2:      1      3       3          FALSE
#3:      2      4       8          FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dplyr solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(user_A2 = pmin(user_A, user_B),
         user_B = pmax(user_A, user_B),
         user_A = user_A2) %>%
  select(-user_A2) %>%
  group_by(user_A, user_B) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(counter), bi_directional = n() > 1) %>%
  as.data.frame
##   user_A user_B sum bi_directional
## 1      1      2  15           TRUE
## 2      1      3   3          FALSE
## 3      2      4   8          FALSE
```

`mutate()` is used to redefine `user_A` and `user_B` such that the smaller of the two values is always in the first column. Then the auxiliary column `user_A2` is dropped. The data is grouped by `user_A` and `user_B` and two summaries are calculated for each group: The sum over `counter` and whether there was more than one value. This latter uses `n()` which counts the number of rows in the group.

The last line uses `as.data.frame` to transform back to a data frame. This is only needed, if you insist on having a data frame as your result.